# pysnmp not handling large string returns

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am trying to walk the sysORTable using the bulkget commandgenerator using the following code based from the samples:

```
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.bulkCmd(
    cmdgen.UsmUserData(user, 
                    authKey=authKey, 
                    privKey=privKey, 
                    authProtocol=authProto, 
                    privProtocol=privProto, 
                    securityEngineId=None
            ),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((sHost, 161)),
    0 , 25, 
    *[cmdgen.MibVariable(oid) for oid in sOID] )
```

However the results returned from the agent are over the 255 character limit imposed by the MIB lookup. I have found two workarounds to this problem:

1. Change the value of the max length of `DisplayString` in pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-TC.py: `subtypeSpec = OctetString.subtypeSpec + ValueSizeConstraint(0, 512)`
2. Disabling MIB lookups in the cmdgen with `lookupMib=False`

However both these fixes, while allowing the script to complete, seem to truncate the output. For example:

```
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(<ObjectName value object at 0x7f1c04686cd0 tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7f1c0c88dad0 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.106]>), <DisplayString value object at 0x7f1c04623150 subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object at 0x7f1c04a64490 consts <ValueSizeConstraint object at 0x7f1c0756c510 consts 0, 65535>, <ValueSizeConstraint object at 0x7f1c04a64450 consts 0, 512>> tagSet <TagSet object at 0x7f1c0c88d5d0 tags 0:0:4> encoding iso-8859-1 payload [Agent capabiliti...B
File name: sys]>)]
```

Note the ellipsis and the line break.

Two questions:

1. How do I fix the truncating of output?
2. What format is this message in and how do I unpack it? (quite different from a standard get output with a key and a value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, this seems like a bug in your SNMP agent - they should not overflow the string. In that sense pysnmp is doing just fine. ;-)

To answer your questions:

1. The ellipsis is only present in `repr()`, it won't happen if you do `str` or `.prettyPrint()` on the value
2. Essentially, it a [sequence of tuples](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectType). Each tuple is (name, value). So to print stuff out you could do this:

:

```
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

The example can be found [here](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/table-operations.html#fetch-scalar-and-table-variables).

Comment: Thank you! I still consider myself a python novice with no formal training in the language. I really appreciate you answering my questions and you patience as you've answered several of mine in the past week... and I doubt this will be the last. I would like to ask more regarding your comment about "This seems like a bug in your SNMP agent". The value returned in one of the items was 498 characters it it seems like a fairly common occurrence. This particular agent is a Cisco agent is is supported by all SNMP managers...

Comment: ... Do the SNMP RFCs declare that a value should not be over a specific size, or is there something else at play here? I have upped the size of the `DisplayString` class to 511 to work round this, but will I break anything else by doing so?